# Assistance with selenium web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the details of the medal of honor that musicians have won! So [here](http://www.cmohs.org/search-results.php?q=&x=40&y=9&rank=Musician&organization=&division=&company=&conflict=) is a link to the list of the musicians. And then when you click on view for each one, it has a neat little table of RANK, COMPANY, DATE OF ISSUE, etc. I want to scrape the data from that table.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/ashkij/Desktop/chromedriver")
driver.get("http://www.cmohs.org/search-results.php?q=&x=40&y=9&rank=Musician&organization=&division=&company=&conflict=")
person = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("div.floatElement.recipientView")
details = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("div.detailDatacol1") 
for i in details:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It does not print...anything. Implying that I obviously did something wrong, even though I pointed the driver to (for example) Datacol1 which had a relevant peice of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First collect all view `href`s then visit each of them and collect target data.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.cmohs.org/search-results.php?q=&x=40&y=9&rank=Musician&organization=&division=&company=&conflict=')

# get hrefs
view_links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('recipientView')
for index, view in enumerate(view_links):
    html = view.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    href = html.split('"')[1]

    view_links[index] = href

# visit each href and get data
for href in view_links:
    driver.get(href)

    detail_data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('dataBar')
    for detail in detail_data:
        print(detail.text)
```

Comment: Hmm, thank you very much for the start! What I'm trying to get, though, is the information from the table _after_ you click on View. That just prints what the information listed on the URL.

Comment: @thewhitetie updated. Sorry, didn't get your point the first time